# Unable to use multiple ngbModal in one component

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to use multiple ngbModal in my angular component. I am able to open and close the first modal successfully. I am getting an error when i try to open second model. How can fix it. Please guide me.

When i click on Test1 button it shows me an error. ERROR TypeError: "this.modalService is undefined"

HTML

```
<button (click)="onClick($event)"></button>
<ng-template #firstTemplate let-modal>
  <div class="modal-footer">
  
    <button type="button" class="btn  btn-primary" (click)="onTest1($event); modal.close('Save click')">test1</button>
  
  </div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #secondTemplate let-modal>
  <div class="modal-footer">
  
    <button type="button" class="btn  btn-primary" (click)="onTest2($event); modal.close('Save click')">test2</button>
  
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

TS

```
@ViewChild('firstTemplate', {static: true}) firstTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild('secondTemplate', {static: true}) secondTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild('disabledEsc', {read: TemplateRef, static: true}) disabledEscTemplate: TemplateRef<HTMLElement>;

constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

 onClick(event) {
    event.srcElement.blur();
    event.preventDefault();
    this.modalService.open(this.firstTemplate, {
      windowClass: 'ngb-modal',
      size: 'lg', scrollable: true, centered: true, backdrop: 'static',
    });

  onTest1(event) {
    console.log(event);
    event.srcElement.blur();
    event.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(this.testModal, 500);
  }

  testModal() {
    this.modalService.open(this.secondTemplate, { //   error
      windowClass: 'ngb-modal',
      size: 'lg', scrollable: true, centered: true, backdrop: 'static',
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the error that modalService is not defined because when the `testModal` method is executed by the setTimeout, the `this` context is not set to the instance of your component.

to fix this you can use an arrow function :

```js
setTimeout(() => this.testModal(), 500);
```

or you can bind the this context of the testModal function to your component :

```js
const boundTestModal = this.testModal.bind(this);
setTimeout(boundTestModal , 500);
```